# Повтор блока try в java

Tags: java, исключения, try-catch

только начинаю java. Хочу чтобы после catch , в случае если ошибка была, try повторялся заново. Думал написать типо такого , но "Вы ввели не число. Пожалуйста , введите только число." начинает бесконечно повторяться если я ввожу не число.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int one = 0;
        int two = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Введите первое число: ");
                exp = scan.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Введите второе число: ");
                money = scan.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Вы ввели не число. Пожалуйста , введите только число.");
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        while(true);
        }
```

Comment: В чём вы вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static int exp = 0;
static int money = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int one = 0;
    int two = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Введите первое число: ");
            exp = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите второе число: ");
            money = scan.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Вы ввели не число. Пожалуйста , введите только число.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо , проглядел вообще про другие переменные, но это я переименовывал и так вышло. все работает, осталось только разобраться , что я сделал не так)